# BigQuery RATIO_TO_REPORT for all data no partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want calculate ratio of specify field, I know in legacy sql I can use RATIO_TO_REPORT function ex:

```
SELECT
  month,
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(totalPoint) over (partition by month)
FROM (
  SELECT
    format_datetime('%Y-%m', ts) AS month,
    SUM(point) AS totalPoint
  FROM
    `userPurchase`
  GROUP BY
    month
  ORDER BY
    month )
```

but I want get ratio that calculate by all data without partition, ex:(this code not work)

```
SELECT
  month,
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(totalPoint) over (partition by "all"),
# RATIO_TO_REPORT(totalPoint) over (partition by null)
FROM (
  SELECT
    format_datetime('%Y-%m', ts) AS month,
    SUM(point) AS totalPoint
  FROM
    `userPurchase`
  GROUP BY
    month
  ORDER BY
    month )
```

It doesn't work, How I can do for same thing? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement RATIO\_TO\_REPORT() in standard SQL in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878410/how-to-implement-ratio-to-report-in-standard-sql-in-bigquery)

Comment: Just don't include the `PARTITION BY` part. For the function itself, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40878410/6253347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the rest of the code is correct  - just omit `partition by` part

```
RATIO_TO_REPORT(totalPoint) OVER ()
```